# How do I place an object on top of another object in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am able to place an object through `RayCast`  **but it is placing objects inside each other**. **I want it to detect collisions** so that **if an object is under that, then it must place the new object on top of it**. Or **if collides on left it must place object on its right.**

Here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class targetPosition : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject obj;
    Vector3 newPosition;
    void Start () {
        newPosition = transform.position;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) //It places cube on left click
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                newPosition = hit.point;
                GameObject obj1 = Instantiate(obj,newPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                obj1.SetActive (true);

            }
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (1)) //deletes cube on right click
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi. you should look into colliders: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html . Remember that you can use them as triggers too (you will  need few of them in your project). So on cube placement, you need to check witch trigger is used, and move cube up or right or whatever...

Answer (score 2):

With this code you can  detect the what side of the objcet your ray hit. From then on you need to instantiate your object with a certain offset from that point.

```
Vector3 normalOfHit;
     void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) //It places cube on left click
            {
                RaycastHit hit;
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                {
                    normalOfHit = hit.normal;
                    normalOfHit = hit.transform.TransformDirection(normalOfHit);

                    if(normalOfHit == hit.transform.up)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Hit top side");
                    }
                    if (normalOfHit ==  -hit.transform.up)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Hit bottom side");
                    }
                    if (normalOfHit == hit.transform.right)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Hit right side");
                    }
                    if (normalOfHit == -hit.transform.right)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Hit left side");
                    }
                    if(normalOfHit == hit.transform.forward)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Hit front side");
                    }
                    if(normalOfHit == -hit.transform.forward)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Hit back of object");
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```